# How to set RAILS_PRODUCTION_KEY config var on a Rails 6 app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-6

I created a new Rails 6 app and since it supports Multi Environment Credentials I'm trying to use the `RAILS_PRODUCTION_KEY` config var and delete the default `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`

```
heroku config:unset RAILS_MASTER_KEY 
heroku config:set RAILS_PRODUCTION_KEY=`cat config/credentials/production.key`
```

This doesn't work however, and I was able to get it to work after setting `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` to the production key

```
heroku config:unset RAILS_PRODUCTION_KEY
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/credentials/production.key`
```

How do I get Heroku to recognize `RAILS_PRODUCTION_KEY` in a Rails 6 app?

Comment: I think you've discovered the solution yourself: simply trick Heroku into using the production key by assigning it to the master key. Or do you need to have both keys on Heroku?

Comment: No, it was just to satisfy my OCD to name the production key var as RAILS_PRODUCTION_KEY but this works fine

Answer (score 29):

I struggled with figuring out this issue, too. (It's *not* a Heroku-specific issue.)

Bottom line: an environment variable named `RAILS_PRODUCTION_KEY` (or any other Rails environment-flavored variable name) is *not a thing*–Rails doesn't pay attention to it.

From the (weak, IMO) Rails documentation on the Rails 6 credentials feature, I had **wrongly** assumed that the production key (either in the `RAILS_PRODUCTION_KEY` env variable or `config/credentials/production.key`) would decrypt `config/credentials/production.yml.enc`, the master key (either in the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env variable or `config/master.key`) would decrypt `config/credentials.yml.enc`, **and** that a value for a given secrets key in `config/credentials/production.yml.enc` would override the value for that key in `config/credentials.yml.enc`. This is **not** the case.

This is how it **actually** works:

1. Rails 6 uses a **single** key to decrypt a **single** encrypted secrets file.
2. The default location of the decryption key is `config/master.key` and the default location of the secrets file is `config/credentials.yml.enc`.
3. If an environment variable of `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` is defined, Rails will read the decryption key from the environment variable, *not* from `config/master.key`.
4. When running in a given Rails environment (`production`/`development`/etc.), if a corresponding secrets file exists in `config/credentials` (e.g., `config/credentials/production.yml.enc`), then Rails will use *that* secrets file **only**, and it will use the corresponding decryption key (e.g., `config/credentials/production.key`) **only** to decrypt it.
5. If an environment variable of `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` is defined, Rails will read the decryption key from the environment variable, *not* from the decryption key file. NOTE: regardless of the Rails environment, the environment variable that overrides the decryption key file is *always* `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`.

Comment: This is the answer. I also thought it worked the way you thought, and that's how it SHOULD work because I feel like trying to have different keys in development vs. production will be a nightmare to manage, since I'll want to copy everything from development and override some things in production... My head is spinning already

Comment: This answer finally solved it for me along with this one, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66092950/4408829

Comment: omg, thank you! I've just spent hours trying to figure out why `RAILS_PRODUCTION_KEY` doesn't do anything.