# Difference between master.key and production.key and other {environment}.key files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I'm using ActiveRecord encrypted fields in my app and generating credentials using the following command: `rails credentials:edit --environment development` (same for `test` and `production` ).

Now I have 4 files:
`config/credentials/development.key`
`config/credentials/test.key`
`config/credentials/production.key`
`config/master.key`

What's the difference between the master key and all the environment keys?

Comment: Some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65554027/328915)

Answer (score 1):

The master key is used to encrypt and decrypt credentials in all environments. The environment keys are used to encrypt and decrypt credentials in their respective environments.

Answer (score 0):

`credentials.yml.enc`/`master.key` is the pair for global secrets. It was added in rails 5.

Rails 6 added the environment specific ones like `production.yml.enc`/`production.key`. For backwards compatibility reasons the global one is still available. If the current environment specific one are not detected then rails will use the global one.

I'd suggest to always use the env specific ones, remove the global ones altogether or leave it as template.